# Extinction Burst in Humans

Tags: behavior, habituation, self-control

I've recently been exposed to the term [extinction burst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_(psychology)#Extinction_burst) and was wondering how it applies to adult humans and habit modification and behavior management.

All the research I've found focuses on animals and generally fails to extend the results to adult humans. Usually limiting to toddlers and animals in application.

Is there any research that points to adults being able to limit behavior through extinction without outside help (teachers, therapists, psychologist, etc.) in their own habits?

Research on topic:
[Extinction and Memory (APA)](http://www.apa.org/science/about/psa/2007/12/lattal.aspx)
[What is Extinction (VeryWell)](https://www.verywell.com/what-is-extinction-2795176)

Comment: Excellent question! Could you also link to the research you found on your own?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! That really improved the question.